# Quick Sort Average and Worst case complexity confusion?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I am a little confused regarding the Average and Worst Case of Quick sort. I know the following:

1. Quick sort has average case complexity of O(nlogn) when the middle pivot is chosen.
2. Quick sort Worst case complexity is when the Minimum or Maximum element is chosen as the pivot.
3. Both the above cases will provide the same complexity for a almost sorted list of elements and a list of unsorted data.

Are the above three points true? If not I would like to know how Quick sort would behave for an almost sorted list and an unsorted list?

Comment: Item 2: The pivot is not chosen once! But once for each iteration.  Therefore I believe that the question by the op is not well posed.

Answer (score 3):

You're right about (1) and (2). Quicksort behaves well when the pivot divides the data approximately in half (so ideally the pivot is the median), and less well when the division is uneven.

The significance of whether the input data is sorted or not depends on how the pivot is chosen.

The simplest possible choice of pivot is to take the first element of the section you're partitioning. If you do that, and if the data is sorted or reverse-sorted, then you get the most uneven possible division, because the pivot you've chosen is the least or greatest value in the range.

The next simplest, I suppose, is to take as pivot the element halfway along the input. Then if the data is already sorted, you get the best possible division. Hurrah! But it's still possible that this middle element is the least (or greatest) value in the range, in which case you get a bad division. Boo!

Better choices of pivot can be made with various techniques: "median-of-three", "pseudo-median-of-nine", or at random (in which case a malicious user can't construct a worst-case to send you, and the probability of a bad case is so tiny for inputs of significant size that in practice you can't reasonably care).

You could even use median-of-medians quickselect to find the median in linear time and use that as a pivot, thus avoiding an O(n^2) worst case altogether. Actually, though, there's a better way to avoid an O(n^2) worst case: Introsort.

When people talk about "quick sort", they don't necessarily mean any particular choice of pivot, so you can't say what quick sort would do without specifying a choice. The very first description of Quicksort by Hoare used the first element as pivot, I think, so it's slow for nearly-sorted or nearly-reverse-sorted data.